# Minikube не может спулить image из Yandex cloud private container registry

Tags: kubernetes

Я новенький в k8s и я пробую использовать private container registry от Яндекс облака. Minikube пытается спулить image, но падает из-за ошибки аутентификации
Выполнив `kubectl describe pod <pod_name>`
Выдает

```
...
Warning  Failed          28s                  kubelet            Failed to pull image "cr.yandex/<container_registry_id>/hcm/frontend:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: Authentication problem ;...
```

До этого я выполнил команду `yc container registry configure-docker` отсюда [официальная дока](https://cloud.yandex.ru/docs/container-registry/operations/authentication#cred-helper), чтобы залогиниться в докере

Скопировал креды из конфига докера в minikube

```
kubectl create secret generic regcred \
    --from-file=.dockerconfigjson=<path/to/.docker/config.json> \
    --type=kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
```

[из официальной документации](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#registry-secret-existing-credentials)

Что я делаю не так? Нужно ли использовать `minikube addons registry-creds`?

Answer (score 0):

В [документации](https://cloud.yandex.com/en-ru/docs/container-registry/operations/authentication#method) сказано:

> After specifying all the parameters, set cr.yandex as the address for authentication. Otherwise, the request will be sent to the default service, Docker Hub.

Поэтому достаточно использовать:

```
minikube addons configure registry-creds
```

Указать там server url `cr.yandex`, добавить логин и пароль, потом выполнить

```
minikube addons enable registry-creds
```

и все заработает.